# Hyphen and vertical line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am trying to decipher the following code:

```
awk '{print "aws s3 cp ###"$4" - | gunzip | awk -F $\"\\t\" '"'"'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {if ($287 == \"0\" && tolower($295)) print $11}'"'"' > "gensub(/.+\/(.+tsv\.gz)/,output_path"\\1.txt",$4)}'
```

However, I am not sure about a couple of things:

1) What "-" does. I know "|" is used for piping but I really am not sure about "-" except in the context of negating some option. I tried googling "ubuntu hyphen/minus/dash" but nothing came up related to this

2) I am not sure about `print "aws s3 cp ###"$4"` either. It normally prints the lines satisfying the if conditions but here it takes an aws command string, following by $4 which I know is a column index

3) Also, I know that `awk -F` followed by a sign will designate the sign as the separator but here there is no sign. I do not understand the default behaviour in this case.

Comment: `what "-" does.` - is is printed out. It's `print "blabal"$4"blabla - | blabla"`. It's a string.

Comment: @KamilCuk Oh, thanks a lot. I wonder why we don't need "\-" to interpret this symbol literally

Comment: Anyway, looks like `awk` is used to construct something bigger that looks like `aws s3 cp ###$4 - | gunzip | awk ...`. Look at `aws` comand  on how to interpret `-`.

Comment: @KamilCuk I was looking into "aws documentation" but could not anything useful. Did you mean to say awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a truly awful command line.

1) The hyphen is an option to the `aws s3 cp` command. It's unusual to see it used this way but it means that the destination of the copy is STDOUT and thus gets piped into `gunzip`. It's much more common to see a hyphen represent STDIN for data being piped *into* a command.

2) The `print` is outputting the `aws s3 cp` command along with all the rest of the pipeline (including an embedded instance of another AWK command).

3) The "sign" for the `-F` here is a tab character using (improperly) Bash's translation quoting (`$" "`). It should have used Bash's ANSI quoting (`$' '`) which allows for interpreting backslash escapes (`\t` represents the tab character). In any case, it's wasted since AWK can understand `\t` for `-F` without any special quoting.

This appears to be a variable that must be set elsewhere: `output_path`

The pipeline that is output by the outer AWK command will need to be fed to the shell in order to be executed.

Comment: But where in this awful command is `aws` actually executed? The input to `gunzip` is the output of `print`, not of `aws`, which I feel is somewhat odd.

Comment: @user1934428: No, the print _includes_ the `gunzip` and the next `awk`. Follow the open and close quotes to see that. We don't get to see where this gets executed in the part that the OP posted. The output of the `print` (which is the _whole_ pipeline) has to get piped somewhere into `sh` (or some other shell). I mentioned that in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: I see now. A somewhat weird way to do scripting.

Comment: Building up a command string and piping it into a shell or other interpreter is a common technique. This one is awful because of a lot of awkward quoting, its overall length, using `awk` inside `awk`, complex filename manipulation and very high field numbers (without meaningful  variable names to refer to them). It comes from a pathological desire to create an all-in-one oneliner instead of writing readable and maintainable code.